# Cant call data, first time writing database joins

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to write my first query that uses a database join. I've gone off a tutorial website, only it doesn't seem to be display anything, Can anybody see any obvious errors with my code?

```
//USers with Same Interests
$interests_query = "SELECT * 
                      FROM produgg_users AND user_interests 
                     WHERE produgg_users.id = user_interests.user_id 
                       AND (interest = $interest1 
                         OR interest = $interest2 
                         OR interest = $Interest3)";
$interests_result = mysql_query($interests_query);

if($interests_result != 0) {
  while($interests_row = mysql_fetch_array($interests_result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row->id;
  } 
} else {
  echo "No users to display!";
}
//END SAME INTERESTS
```

---

Going of @Jay answer I now have this only its still not bringing back any information, just printing out "No users to diaply"

```
//USers with Same Interests
$interest1 = "footy";
$interests_query = "SELECT * FROM produgg_users
                     join user_interests on produgg_users.id = user_interests.user_id
                     where interest = $interest1 OR interest = $interest2 OR interest = $Interest3";
$interests_result = mysql_query($interests_query);

if($interests_result != 0) {
while($interests_row = mysql_fetch_array($interests_result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row->id;
} 
}
else
{
echo "No users to display!";
}
//END SAME INTERESTS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have `... mysql_query($interests_query) or die(mysql_error())` to catch any syntax errors.

mysql_query() does not return "0" if there's no results. It returns a result handle, or a boolean false to indicate the query totally failed. You can check how many rows matched with `mysql_num_rows($interests_result)`

Comment: Ahhh, thats now led to this, thanks....
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OR interest =' at line 3

Comment: Echo out the query string you're building, to see exactly what it is.. I'm guessing it's that `$Interest3`. variables are case sensitive in PHP, and probably you intend to use `$interest3`.

Comment: Ive removed them all and just stuck with 1 var for now, I receive this error though.....Unknown column 'footy' in 'where clause'....I want to select all rows where the interest value is qual to 'footy', I presume I need to somehow specify this?

Comment: Nevermind, I wrapped my variable in the where clause in '' and it's worked, thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

Try your query with a JOIN to link the two tables.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM produgg_users 
        INNER JOIN user_interests
            ON produgg_users.id = user_interests.user_id
    WHERE (interest = $interest1 OR interest = $interest2 OR interest = $Interest3)
```

Comment: Ponies: True, though it won't make any difference if it's an inner join.

Comment: @Jay: `IN` is the logical equivalent, but it is generally optimized to run better than `OR`s.

Comment: @Ponies: Actually I completely misread your comment. I thought you were saying to move the interest = stuff into the "on" clause. To your actual suggestion: Whether it's better optimized or not, IN is certainly more readable because it makes it immediately clear to the reader that we are testing the same field and not 3 different fields.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM produgg_users AND user_interests WHERE produgg_users.id = user_interests.user_id AND (interest = $interest1 OR interest = $interest2 OR interest = $Interest3)";

Your key problem is that that's not the correct syntax for a join. You don't say "and" between the table names. You either put a comma and then give the join conditions in the where clause (old, clumsy style), or you write "join" and put the join conditions in an "on" clause (new, pretty style).

Old style:

```
SELECT * FROM produgg_users, user_interests
WHERE produgg_users.id = user_interests.user_id
AND (interest = $interest1 OR interest = $interest2 OR interest = $Interest3)
```

New style:

```
SELECT * FROM produgg_users
join user_interests on produgg_users.id = user_interests.user_id
where interest = $interest1 OR interest = $interest2 OR interest = $Interest3
```